# Need Regex value to match correctly for my input text

Tags: c#, regex, match

I have following string and need a regex to match it with returning values and keys.

guid="b3b63ef4-ebb3-4983-9c4e-0eccf77ec32c" name="test.testName"

I have used following code but sounds there is a problem with that:

```
Regex.Matches(s, "(\\w+)=\"([\\w\\.:\\?/=]+)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled)
```

What I get is just name="test.testName" not the guid.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp currently doesn't allow hyphens. Try:

```
Regex.Matches(s, "(\\w+)=\"([\\w\\.:\\-\\?/=]+)\"", ...params...);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're not matching the `-` in your guid. It's not in `\w` nor is it in any of the other parts of your character class.

If you're sure about the format of your input, you could try matching with

```
Regex.Matches(s, "(\\w+)=\"([^\"]+)\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

This matched a word, an equals sign, an opening double-quote and then a number of *anything that is **not** a double-quote* followed by a closing double-quote.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
Regex.Matches(s, @"(\w+)=""([^""]*)""",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```